# When running a project "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When running a project, an error occurs:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
> 'sqlServerQueryDaoImpl' defined in file SqlServerQueryDaoImpl.class :
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

**Code**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlserverEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "sqlserverTransactionManager",
    basePackages = "com.server.dao.sqlserverDao"
)
public class SqlserverConfiguration {

/**
 * Sqlserver datasource definition.
 *
 * @return datasource.
 */
@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.sqlserver.datasource")
public DataSource sqlserverDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}

/**
 * Entity manager definition.
 *
 * @param builder an EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.
 * @return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.
 */
@Primary
@Bean(name = "sqlserverEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
sqlserverEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(sqlserverDataSource())
            .properties(hibernateProperties())
            .packages("com.server.entity.sqlserver")
            .persistenceUnit("sqlserverPU")
            .build();
}

/**
 * @param entityManagerFactory
 * @return
 */
@Primary
@Bean(name = "sqlserverTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager 
sqlserverTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sqlserverEntityManager") 
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}

private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {

    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("sqlserver-hibernate.cfg.xml");
    try {
        Properties properties = 
PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
        return properties.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                        e -> e.getValue())
                );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new HashMap<String, Object>();
     }
 }
}
```

**Dao**

```
package com.server.dao.sqlserverDao;

import com.server.entity.postgresql.DayVisits;
import java.util.List;

public interface SqlServerDao {

List<DayVisits> getDayVisits(int startDate, int finishDate, long branchKey, 
long serviceKey);

}
```

**DaoImpl**

```
package com.server.dao.sqlserverDao;
import com.server.entity.postgresql.DayVisits;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class SqlServerQueryDaoImpl implements  SqlServerDao {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="sqlserverPU")
private EntityManagerFactory sqlserverEntityManager;

public SqlServerQueryDaoImpl(EntityManagerFactory sqlserverEntityManager) {
    this.sqlserverEntityManager = sqlserverEntityManager;
}

Session session = sqlserverEntityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

@Override
public List<DayVisits> getDayVisits(int startDate, int finishDate, long 
branchKey, long serviceKey){
String sql ="select dd.year, dd.month, dd.day_of_month, dd.day_of_week,\n" +
           "count(fvt.id) as visit_count\n" +
           "from stat.fact_visit_transaction fvt \n" +
           "join stat.dim_date dd on date_key=dd.id\n" +
           "where branch_key =:serviceKey \n" +
           "and service_key =:branchKey\n" +
           "and date_key between :startDate and :finishDate \n" +
           "group by dd.year, dd.month, dd.day_of_month, dd.day_of_week\n" +
           "order by dd.year, dd.month, dd.day_of_month, dd.day_of_week\n";
   Query q = session.createNativeQuery(sql).addEntity(DayVisits.class);
   q.setParameter("startDate",startDate);
   q.setParameter("finishDate",finishDate);
   q.setParameter("branchKey",branchKey);
   q.setParameter("serviceKey",serviceKey);
   List<DayVisits> dayVisitsList =((NativeQuery) q).list();

   return dayVisitsList;
   }
  }
```

my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.arithmos</groupId>
<artifactId>WebAppForecast</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Forecast</name>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
     8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<!-- Unit Test -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- Spring Core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Spring boot -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <!-- SqlServer -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- PostgreSQL -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- JAVA EE 8 API -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>8.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Servlet Library -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- jstl -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>WebAppForecast</finalName>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.10.v20180503</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>8</source>
      <target>8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

stacktrace

```
09:42:56.171 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlServerQueryDaoImpl' defined in file [C:\aritmos\target\classes\com\server\dao\sqlserverDao\SqlServerQueryDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@12a3b37{/,file:///C:/Users/alena.s/aritmos/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/alena.s/aritmos/src/main/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlServerQueryDaoImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\alena.s\aritmos\target\classes\com\server\dao\sqlserverDao\SqlServerQueryDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: Please share your build configuration (pom.xml or build.gradle)

Comment: done, please help me. I can`t understand why this is happening

Comment: Try to change "@PersistentContext" to "@PersistenceUnit" on top of EntityManagerFactory field

Comment: I tried it did not help

Comment: Is this publicly available code? There's might be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: yes, I can make an archive and upload it

Comment: Please remove the archive, it contains some sensitive data. I'll post answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are multiple problems found:

First, of all. You've mixed plain Spring and Spring Boot application/configuration.

For example, this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Already contains these two artifacts:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

There's no need to duplicate them (unless you need specific version of it), since you're using `spring-boot-starter` packages.

Then your `@SpringBootApplication` class should be in the root directory of your app, in order to scan all the packages recursively, like this (note package):

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then, coming to a problem with two data sources.

**PostgresqlConfiguration**

Change

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(postgresqlDataSource())
                .properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages("com.server.entity.postgresql")
                .persistenceUnit("postgresqlPU")
                .build();
```

To

```
@Bean(name = "postgresqlEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresqlEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(postgresqlDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.server.entity.postgresql");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("postgresqlPU");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

        return factoryBean;
    }
```

Similarly do the same for **SqlserverConfiguration.java** class.

In **SqlServerQueryDaoImpl.java** do the following changes:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="sqlserverPU")
private EntityManager sqlserverEntityManager;

public SqlServerQueryDaoImpl(@Qualifier("sqlserverEntityManager")EntityManagerFactory sqlserverEntityManager) {
    this.sqlserverEntityManager = sqlserverEntityManager.createEntityManager();
    session = sqlserverEntityManager.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

In order to disable Spring auto configuration for data source (HikariCP will scan for it), add the following to `application.properties`:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

No other changes needed.

Then you have a problem with `@Cache` in your entities. You did not specify nor you've added cache provider to class path, so it can't find a provider and fails on the startup. Just remove `@Cache` annotation from `DayVisits.java` and `IntervalVisits.java`.

Then add `@Transient` to this setter:

```
@Transient
public List<IntervalVisits> getIntervalVisits() {
    return intervalVisits;
}
```

Then add setter to `week_num` field. JPA will scan for it.

```
public void setWeek_num(int week_num) {
    this.week_num = week_num;
}
```

And the last one, you need to add JSONB bean implementation to the classpath:

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
          <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

After all this changes were done, I was able to start the app on embedded Tomcat.

I'd also suggest to get rid of all ***.xml** configuration files. Move everything to `application.properties` and read it from there.

In general, try to minimize customization of Spring app, unless you're totally understanding what you're doing. Spring Boot provides tons of ways how to bootstrap your project with minimum effort. For example, this article shows an example of Spring Boot app with 2 data sources: https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Overall, in order to get the project running some moderate refactoring is really needed.

Good luck with it.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much.

Comment: Thanks for your time!